# How to generate evenly sized polygons within a boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, polygon-creation

I have an area and need to create evenly sized polygons within the area. It doesn't matter where the polygons fall, only that they don't overlap and each area is the same. They needn't be squares/rectangles or any specific shape. Can this be done in ArcGIS?

Comment: Specifically, I have a polygon file representing the boroughs of London and I want to create polygons within the limits of the London boroughs that are evenly-sized. It is okay if individual polygons overlap two boroughs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/tooldesc.php

Download Hawth's Tools and make a grid (Sampling Tools > Create Vector Grid). Grid squares can be set up to specific sizing and each is a separate polygon. Clip the grid by the existing boroughs map.

Comment: Is it the same in GME? I believe Hawth's Tools was discontinued 5 years ago.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/genvecgrid.htm